# Django unable to save unicode string in MySQL (OperationalError - 1366, "Incorrect string value")

Tags: python, mysql, django, unicode

I've got a `TextField` in one of my models.  I tried inserting a string of Japanse characters into the database and I got this error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/pages/page/add/
(1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xE3\\x83\\x91\\xE3\\x83\\xAF...' for column 'body' at row 1")
```

I thought that Django, Python, and MySQL supported Unicode and uses it first.  What is going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: Check my notes on Python:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the Python/Django related issue. Your MySQL table column doesn't supports the unicode format you are currently using.

Default character set used by MySQL is `utf-8`. If you want to change character set for any particular column, you may run the query as:

```
ALTER TABLE db.table MODIFY COLUMN my_column VARCHAR(255)
CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;
```

where:

- db: your database
- table: name of the table
- my_column: name of column you want to modify

Comment: shouldn't utf-8 handle Japanese characters?

Answer (score 1):

you only need to do flowing while saving the value.

```
 class Employee(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super(Employee, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
           self.name = str(self.name.encode('unicode_escape'))
```

- 

> you need to encode with unicode_escape before save as mention in above example (**self.name = str(self.name.encode('unicode_escape'))**) then you will be able to save any value (including Japanese chars)
> and no need to do any other setting or db changes

- 

Answer (score 0):

In `settings.py` add options in database config

```py
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME':  '',
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'}, // this line should help
}
```